# Can I uncraft items with logistic pipes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I've heard that you can convert charcoal into coal by making/disassembling a torch, although this seems like a bug/exploit that may be fixed, and note I haven't tested this yet as I'm not at home.

If this does indeed work, I'd like to automate this if possible, and I was wondering if I could do this with logistic pipes. I was thinking I could set up a crafting pipe to turn sticks and charcoal into torches, and if it's possible uncraft back into coal, so when I request some coal, it would look for sticks and charcoal, create a torch, then disassemble it and give me the coal.

Is it possible to disassemble items with logistics pipes? Or maybe with some other system in FTB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not, the Logistic Pipes mod itself has no method of uncrafting, and the only method I know off is [the Twilight Forest Uncrafting Table](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Uncrafting_Table), which requires experience to uncraft and can not be automated.

If you find a different automatable way of uncrafting you can use the standard [Crafting Logistic Pipes](http://logisticspipes.wikia.com/wiki/Crafting_Logistics_Pipe) to automate it into your Logistic Pipes network.

Comment: Okay, I guess this is one thing I can't do automatically :P. I'll take a look at the Twilight forest table, thanks.

Comment: It's a shame, it goes against my AUTOMATE *ALL THE THINGS* approach to minecraft.

Comment: Haha same approach I have! I've been wanting to venture into making MC mods so I think I might have found my first project :p.